# Is there a way to test if a string is an MD5 hash?

Tags: c#, md5

I am trying to input a text file that contains MD5 hashes and keywords (one per line) into a C# app.  Is there a way to check if a string is an MD5 hash?  I looked on MSDN and couldn't find anything in the MD5 class.

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file contents? Is there any pattern to the data?

Comment: Unfortunately, no I can't.  I don't have a real file to test my  app with.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use Regex like this:

```
public static bool IsMD5(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return Regex.IsMatch(input, "^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$", RegexOptions.Compiled);
}
```

Comment: This 94476226E1DD479C8E1FAB7A8FDEFFFA won't work, the corect regex is  `[0-9a-fA-F]{32}`

Comment: Actually, the Regex should be `^[0-9a-f]{32}$` (with case-insensitive `/i` flag) or `^[0-9a-fA-F]{32}$` as @EduardFlorinescu suggested if you can't set case-insensitive flag. Because `[0-9a-f]{32}` also matches strings that are longer, which can happen but that will not be an MD5 of something, but just any random hex encoded data.

Comment: That won't work for MD5 like this "CBHc/dgtzBCG/xGe8wGBJA==", which is a number by the way

Comment: using `RegexOptions.Compiled` makes no sense here

Answer (score 9):

Well, an MD5 hash is really just binary data - if you've got a string then it's presumably encoded in some fashion, e.g. base64 or hex. You can test whether the string is correctly encoded for the right length of binary (16 bytes). That's all though - while there *may* be binary values which are never the result of hashing any data, I highly doubt that you can recognise such values. Ideally, there should be no such values, of course...

Answer (score 5):

A MD5 hash is a 128 bit value. It is usually represented as a `byte[]` with a length of 16, or as a `string` where each byte is represented by two hexadecimal digits. A MD5 hash has no internal structure or any kind of 'signature' that allows you detect if a 128 bit value is a MD5 hash or not.

Answer (score 3):

if its 32 bytes long and 0-9 a-f its probably md5, but not 100%

Answer (score 1):

First thing to do is examine the file to work out how the MD5 hashes are encoded, then design a match based on that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the correct one is this one that includes also the capitals sometimes hashes come also in capitals so why miss that.

```
[0-9a-fA-F]{32}
```

or

```
[0-9a-f]{32}(?i)
```